# Referring to results of a sub query in main query

Tags: sql

I have a sub query that returns one column, showing as GroupType, I then want to do a CASE function on this result within the main query, however I get an invalid column name when using the CASE statement.

Can i do this in SQL to do I have to refer to it by a different name

Comment: hard to suggest better ways to do this without seeing what code you have. I would suggest though that correlated subqueries are often a poor technique to use to get data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  CASE
        WHEN
        (
        SELECT  column
        FROM    othertable
        ) = 1
        THEN '1'
        ELSE '2'
        END
FROM    mytable
```

To reuse the subquery result:

```
SELECT  subvalue, CASE subvalue WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
FROM    (
        SELECT  (
                SELECT  column
                FROM    othertable
                ) AS subvalue
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
```

Comment: the problem is, I need to use it twice, once to group by the result, and once to change the output based on one group. I was hoping not to have to type the sub query twice.

Comment: Could you please post your query as it is now?